# Why no @interface by default when creating non-controller file?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Just something I've noticed: when you create new files in XCode that are not a subclass of a controller, there is no `@interface` in the .m file by default. I'm going to assume that's done intentionally - I'm curious as to why that is

I was thinking that possibly its because they're making the assumption that you're going to want most of your properties to be publicly accessible for parent controllers and the likes?

I've tried researching this to no avail - help me out SO! :D

Comment: nice observation.. +1.

Comment: I don't know why this would be intentional. You might want to file a bug <https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/>.

Comment: Well it's not a bug. The file just comes out of the box that way. It's perfectly fine to just write an `@interface` in the .m

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd generally be wary of trying to draw any conclusions from Apple's template files - a lot of their sample projects and project templates don't really follow best practices. For example, if you create a project with Core Data, the template has all of the Core Data code within the app delegate - somewhere it really doesn't belong.

On the topic of including an `@interface` class extension within the .m file - I usually have these in most classes, and keep all properties / methods private unless they definitely need to be visible to another class.